# Pytesseract cannot read simple number

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to recognize two numbers from an image.
from this
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1qEO.png)

i processed the image to look like this
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7UiR.png)
and give that to pytesseract and that work easly.

But when i want to read by tesseract from this
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx5DL.png)
to this
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl2Gy.png)
it doesn't work and return empty string

code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


img = cv2.imread('grabbed.png')

rows, cols, channels = img.shape

imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(imggray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx=3,fy=3)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(11,11),0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,9)
k = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='outputbase digits --dpi 300 --psm 13')
print(k)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - check the orientation. pytessaract need perfectly portrait images.
2 - use dialation and errosion
3 https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/ [Look at this example][1]